# Setting timezone not applying?

Tags: php, php-ini

With PHP 5.4 adding warnings to alert of timezone issues, this error is quite common:

> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in somefile.php on line 42

Okay, fair enough. Adding `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` is nice and simple, but I don't want to have to do this for every single script, especially when doing stuff on CLI.

So I added a line to my php.ini file:

```
date.timezone=UTC
```

And... it doesn't work. The warning still appears.

For debugging, I did this:

```
echo file_get_contents(php_ini_loaded_file());
```

And it outputs:

> ```
> extension=./ext/php_gd2.dll
> extension=./ext/php_oauth.dll
> extension=./ext/php_curl.dll
>
> date.timezone=UTC
> ```

The `extension` lines all work - I take them out and I can't use those functions, I put them in and I can. It's just `date.timezone` that's not taking. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try date.timezone = ('America/New_York') for more time zone options check http://us.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: @p.vansia I want UTC though ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. I've had a similar problem on OpenWRT - it turns out you need to
   properly set /etc/localtime

   Chek /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for available timezones (update system if
   needed) and choose your flavor (simply copy the right file).
2. Another problem I've had is having different php.ini files for the
   different versions of php - cgi, fpm, cli, etc. - make sure you've
   added the date.timezone line in all the php.ini files you have on
   your system.

**EDIT**

You may have a second line in your php.ini file like this:

```
; some lines of variables
date.timezone = UTC
; more lines of variables
date.timezone = 
; even more lines
```

, that would effectively overwrite your date.timezone

Comment: Hi blue, thanks for the answer. I should have specified, but I'm running on Windows so I don't have a `/etc/localtime` or `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. Also, I only have one PHP.ini file, and that wouldn't explain `php_ini_loaded_file()` clearly showing the timezone directive.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Have you tried using a timezone from the list of suported timezones -> **[Europe](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php)**?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Please, run a page with only *phpinfo();* in it and find the "Loaded Configuration File". Make sure you have the date.timezone line in that file. FIY - I've just tested it on windows with UTC and it works just fine.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - well, the latter shows that there is "no value" for date.timezone in the php.ini file. Mine says "UTC". Please, edit the file and be careful if you have more than one instance of the date.timezone line! Also, keep in mind that a command line parameter may overwrite this (and others) value.

Comment: As shown in the "php.ini file" screenshot, there is indeed only one instance of that line.