# Why does PHP think it's a bad idea to rely on the system's time zone?

Tags: php, timezone

I'm a bit annoyed of keeping PHP's time zone updated. I really love that everything else on my system trusts that I'm maintaining the system's time zone correctly. Maybe there might be use cases where it could be beneficial to configure PHP differently, but why does PHP warn me about relying on my time zone is not safe?

> Warning: date(): It is **not safe to rely on the system's timezone** settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

Comment: @NicolòMonili you still believe in magic? I thought they abolished that at some point in (or rather after) the middle ages. Science is the magic *de jour*!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be found with a simple [search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=date.timezone+E_WARNING+--+Really+necessary)

Comment: StasM answered this well here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749041/1952201

Comment: @Jack Waaaait… Let me mine more Unicoins to remove that annoying close function.

Comment: @huwiler Even better :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what PHP devs say about it (in the [**related discussion**](http://grokbase.com/p/php/php-internals/135rsq7bzq/php-dev-date-timezone-e-warning-really-necessary-whats-the-rationale)):

> No - you, as an admin, are required to make an informed decision on
>   what you want your timezone to be. There have been way too many bug
>   reports where people had no clue, so now we throw a warning.

Derick Rethans is the author of [this commit](http://marc.info/?l=phpdoc&m=123306411929978) that turned date_warning from `E_STRICT` (in PHP 5.2-) to `E_WARNING` (PHP 5.3+).

The same discussion has quite a sound (yet obviously awkward) solution to this, applied by MediaWiki:

> Actually, the sensible default is what `guess_timezone()` does already,
>   except without the warnings. You can get that behaviour with e.g.
>
> ```
> date_default_timezone_set( @date_default_timezone_get() );
> ```
>
> at the top of your program. That's what MediaWiki does (except with by
>   modifying `error_reporting` instead of using `@`). We stole the idea from
>   another web app. It's more convenient than duplicating the
>   functionality of `guess_timezone()` in the application.
>
> It's Derick's prerogative to annoy all users half to death with
>   warnings, as his way of indicating his distaste for the state of OS
>   support for querying of system timezone. That's the reward we give him
>   for writing lots of date/time code.

The key part of this workaround is `date_default_timezone_get` function, which, in order, returns the default timezone by...

- reading the timezone set using the `date_default_timezone_set()` function (if any)
- reading the TZ environment variable (if non empty) (Prior to `PHP 5.3.0`)
- reading the value of the `date.timezone` ini option (if set)
- querying the host operating system (if supported and allowed by the OS)

Answer (score 9):

Because Derick said so. That's why. This [**internals mailing list thread**](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/135qbh5twa/date-timezone-e-warning-really-necessary-whats-the-rationale) will tell you all about the "logic" behind this decision. The `date.timezone` warning is a constant annoyance for anyone using PHP as a programming language and not as a replacement for knowing how to write code.

More specifically, this behavior drives *me* nuts. I wouldn't normally abuse the SO Q&A system to vent but this warning drives me bananas. Also, it's April 1 so why not?

Comment: Is it really so hard to set `date.timezone` in your `php.ini` file? [Apparently...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760173/setting-timezone-not-applying)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes it is! While maintaining system time zone is a no brainer by simply watching a system's clock, a previously configured PHP time zone will easily overseen on time zone change. OK, it's a rare use case, but I'm moving soon my laptop to the 4th time zone.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's not a question of difficulty. It's about forcing a known anti-pattern (i.e. registry anti-pattern via .ini files) on users. I have exactly *zero* use for a php.ini file when I'm programming as it's an unnecessary global input to my programs. I shouldn't be forced to use a php.ini to run without unnecessary `E_WARNING` messages.

Answer (score 0):

1) using the system Timezone is a [major performance overhead](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54250).

2) implementations of the TZ database by different vendors have historicaly had lots of functional issues

3) there are issues around the [intellectual property](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/10/07/unix_time_zone_database_destroyed/) of the data. Its the threat of claims and the expense of defending them which undermines such projects - not the validity of the claim. The 2011 case was settled out of court meaning that the matter was only resolved in the case of the plaintiff, not for any future challenges.

4) A consequence of (3) is that even if a system administrator is dilligent with updates there may be upstream issues preventing dissemination of revised data

Comment: 1) is referring to a patched Ubuntu PHP. It doesn't show in general why using system TZ should be a performance issue.

Answer (score -2):

PHP is often used by people who *don't* properly maintain their systems, or run on other peoples' systems (shared hosting). If you are properly maintaining your system, then configuring the default PHP timezone separately is simple.

Comment: Your statement "often used by people who don't properly maintain" is based on what? Furthermore I still don't see why it should be worth a warning yelling it is **unsafe**.

Comment: By the millions of PHP hosting servers, serving tens of millions of PHP driven sites as compared to the number of businesses who can afford to use dedicated resources.

Comment: My statement is based on over a decade of experience as a professional PHP software developer, working both in large organizations (as I do now) and as an independent contractor (owned my own software development company). I've seen almost every type of people who need "PHP programmers" or "web development". A full 80% of PHP websites that I have seen do not have a proper server admin.

Comment: How does this answer OPs question?

Comment: uhm, the default time zone is set initially in the ini file. It's a really different matter then "the lack of maintenance" as you're insisting. At recent PHP installments, the default timezone is set to UTC per default. Either the OP is using old versions or has borked the ini file.